# Why isn't "this" equal to the object that called the function?

Tags: javascript, object, events, methods, window

I have a function that I attach to a dom object. I want to be able to reference the dom object from within the function, but when I call it from an event, `this` isn't equal to the right thing.

```
var main = document.getElementById('main');

main.testFunction = () => {
  console.log('this',this);
}

main.addEventListener('click', main.testFunction);
```

Instead it's equal to `window`. Why is this? How do I reference the object that the method is part of?

Comment: Do not use the function arrow expression, they work _without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords_, change your expresion to `main.testFunction = function() {...}` and it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using arrow function. Arrow function doesnot have their own `this`. Use normal function it will work. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although **without its own bindings to the `this`**

```js
var main = document.getElementById('main');
main.testFunction = function() {
  console.log('this',this);
}
main.addEventListener('click', main.testFunction);
```

```html
<button id="main"> main</button>
```

Secondly when you use `addEventListener` and pass the function then the element to which event is attached is automatically binded to given function.See the snippet

```js
var main = document.getElementById('main');
function testFunction(){
  console.log('this',this);
}
main.addEventListener('click', testFunction);
```

```html
<button id="main"> main</button>
```

If you want to access the element inside arrow function use `event.target` instead of `this`

```js
var main = document.getElementById('main');
main.testFunction = (e) => {
  console.log('this',e.target);
}
main.addEventListener('click', main.testFunction);
```

```html
<button id="main"> main</button>
```

Comment: Seems my actual problem was passing the function as an argument, so thanks for the detailed answer.